# Use 3rd party tools with opsview

Tags: nagios, opsview

How can I use 3rd party tools like nagstamon nagios monitoring or the iphone tools with opsview? there is no cgi-bin anymore it seems (you get redirected to status/hostgroup)

Comment: I asked one of the developers of a third party tool, he said I might try to switch to basic authentication, cant seem to find how to do that :(

Answer (score 1):

Nagstamon SVN version is capable of connect to Opsview servers: http://sourceforge.net/scm/?type=svn&group_id=236865

Comment: Hmm. Port that to maemo / n900 / wtfever they're calling the platform next month and I'll be golden!